# Node.js webscraper

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to get the title of the products in the url that is a variable in the coding. I do not understand what and why that error once I run my program.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
    url = 'https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/Food/Pantry/Canned-%26-Jarred/Broth/plp/RCSS001008003013?productBrand=Campbell%27s';

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);


    const products = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(
            "#site-content > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.product-grid > div.product-grid__results > div.product-grid__results__products > ul > li > div > div > div.product-tile__details > div.product-tile__details__info > h3 > a > span > span.product-name__item.product-name__item--name"))
            .map(partner => partner.innerText.trim())
    )

    console.log(products);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

if a run it in a different web page, it works, as you may run the code below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
    url = 'https://shop.saveonfoods.com/store/A8931118/?_ga=2.134607602.2014665139.1585878612-229336869.1585197564/#/category/576,654,882/broth/1?queries=fq%3Dbrand%253ACampbell%2527s%26sort%3DBrand';

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);


    const products = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(
            '#content > div > div.main > ul > li > div.product__itemContent ' +
            '> div.productInfo.productDetails > hgroup > h3'))
            .map(partner => partner.innerText.trim())
    )

    console.log(products);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: What is the precise error? Do you actually get an error message or do you just not receive results? I suspect that your selector in the first snippet is overly specific or possibly contains errors. Have you tried to apply it in the debugging console of the browser?

Comment: I always get an empty array in the first program. Once, I got a rejection that I didn't know what it was. 
You may see in the second program that there is always a list of products and in the second one I receive nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check for myself as the first site reports that access is denied and the second wouldn't load in the first place. Your comment suggests that the selector is malformed, probably being overly specific. Manually enter `document.querySelectorAll(...);` in the browser's debug console on the page you are scraping, replacing `...` with the target selector. Relax that selector until the call produces a non-empty `NodeList` object.

Comment: If I do the document.querySeletorAll using the terminal inside the website it retrieves the information that I want, but when I run the same code in the web scraper javascript it doesn't let me retrieve it